# Cancel iOS update on iPad

Tags: ios, software-update

I have an iPad 4 + WiFi + 32 GB with me and it was showing me an update to iOS 6.1.3. I haven't selected it as there are multiple issues with lock screen and battery. Today accidentally I clicked on Update. Is there any way to cancel the update?

Also, I have a good score on Temple Run and Temple Run 2. Will the game data be available after the software update or will it be removed? Is there a way to back it up somewhere or transfer it to another iDevice?

*ps: I have already searched for this, and got answers like removing SIM (I don't have one) or recording content till the space gets exhausted. Filling up 32 GB is not an easy task. Is there any other good method to make this?*

Comment: For the Game data, normally it's backed up when you sync your device with iTunes and/or when you enabled iCloud backup. Downgrading iOS (thus "cancelling" the update) is only possible with use of some tools (that are meant for jailbreaking normally) but only if you have your old iOS shsh blobs which I'm sure you don't have.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Currently it is asking for "Do you want to install". I am just giving NO. :) So, thanks. Waiting for a better permanent solution.